How to repair Missing winload.efi error if using legacy mode allows me to boot?
I've installed a new SSD on a laptop that previously used a harddisk with Windows 10 on it. I used a USB to install a new Windows 10 on the new SSD, all is going fine, but when the new windows boot, it shows an error "Missing winload.efi".
I've googled and tried enabling legacy mode support. It boots without issue, and I can use this installation.
However, I want to go back to disabling legacy mode support. How can I do this?
Both harddisk and SSD are already formatted with GPT

and legacy mode support is enabled in BIOS


“How can I do this?” - Convert the disk to GPT using MBR2GPT. This requires a specific partition layout. If your disk qualifies for the conversion is not clear. Only GPT supports UEFI Mode (I.e CSM disabled).

@Ramhoundthe both disk are already on GPT. What else the requirements?

If you are boot Windows 10 in Legacy mode that’s impossible. Provide a screenshot of Disk Management

@Ramhound edited the requested photos in the question

On your firmware implementation it will boot in UEFI mode, if the OS supports it, so I retract the original explanation and modify it to indicate you need to update the EFI entry. You won’t be able to boot Windows 11 in UEFI mode and Windows 10 in Legacy Mode.

@Ramhound so the problem is the windows 10 was set to boot up in legacy mode, that's why the windows 11 is not able to boot up in UEFI? I think windows 10 is set up as UEFI because before installing the windows 11, the windows 10 booted up with the non-legacy support without problem

-Your screenshots blocked the partitions so I can’t determine if both system partitions are on a MBR or GPT disk. Only one definitely is, this probably is, just an EFI entry problem (the entry for the non-working install points to the wrong partition)

I thought both disks are already GPT? First screenshot says both partition style is GPT, If it's an EFI entry problem, how can I rectify the entry?

You have not provided enough information to identify what entries you have or the information to identify each partition on the disk.
